# Why do I need to reference all packages in a WPF appl. that are referenced by another project

Tags: c#

There are two C# projects together in one solution

- Net.Company.Core
- Net.Company.Application

The Core project references a few NuGet packages (e.g. LiteDB 4.1.4). The Application project references the Core project directly (i.e. not via NuGet).

Now when I want to run the Application project I'm getting an exception that a reference to any of the NuGet packages, referenced in the Core project, is not found (FileNotFoundException). In order to resolve this error I also reference the NuGet packages in the Application project.

**Question:** Why does the Application project need to reference these packages as well? My assumption is that the Core project already brings in these references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Application Project Runs - it runs from its own bin/Debug folder. If you check the contents of that folder you will find the Core project dll and other stuff. But not the dll's libraries/nugets that core project needs. So when the Application project code uses the Core Project and the Core project uses one of those Nugets/libs... it fails becuase those libaries arent in the output (current executing folder).

One way to solve this would be to set the Build Output folder of Core project to be same as that of the Application project.

Comment: So in other words. Because the Application project does not reference them in the packages.config file and only the dll is included from the Core project they are simply not there.

Comment: In all honesty - Application project doesnt need them in packages.config - because it doesnt directly use them. This situation has happened because you have added project reference of Core project into Application project. Preferred way would be to Bundle your Core Project as a nuget (with all dependencies assigned) - then use that Core project nuget in the Application project. So all dependencies will come along.

Comment: Yes. This is what I do in general. Here, the application project is just a test tool to test and verify the latest changes to the core project before they go live. That's why it is directly bundled to it. All "real" projects that use the core do include it via NuGet package.